# Javascript Variable Naming For Loop Problem

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Can someone help me figure out why naming a variable changes the random value so much?  I'm stumped.

In the first picture, you can see that the maximum value of the X value will be a random value between 25 and 300. However, EVER TIME I run the code, the lines are super short.

When I make a top_limit variable, shown in the second picture, the lines have true random lengths.

Can someone shed some light on what's happening here? There's no difference between the two pieces of code, in my opinion. One just has a variable name and the other doesn't. No?

[image: without variable naming]

[image: with variable naming]

Comment: please include code snippets rather than images

Comment: You can show the result as a screenshot, but the code must be in text from

Comment: *"One just has a variable name and the other doesn't. No?"* - More accurately... one invokes an operation once and stores the result of that operation in a variable, the other invokes the operation over and over.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

When your random is in a for(,,), it is called on every iteration of the loop. So, in each iteration it changes.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that JS hardcoded those top and bottom limits and then just the code INSIDE the loop kept iterating. I didn't realize it reset each time.